# Force update for an app already published in Google Play Store

Tags: android

I have published an app on Google Play Store, but because the first version has a bug in an API call, i want to force all people that have installed the app to update it, so the problem will fix. How can i do that?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot.

What you can do to prevent this in the future, is to implement [In-App updates](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates).
This will allow you to prompt the user to update. Or just to remind them an update is available. Unfortunately, that will not help you now.

Good luck